# light fixture wattage question

Tags: lighting

I purchased a light kit that requires 3 light bulbs and says 100 Watt max.  Does this mean that the wattage of the 3 bulbs can only add up to 100 watts or does that mean that each lightbulb can be no more than 100 watts.  For example, can I use 3 60 watt bulbs?

Comment: I would think that the _100 watt max_ applies to each socket rather than being what the fixture must not exceed in sum. You could put three 100 watt bulbs in those 3 sockets.

Answer (score -1):

The wattage ratings are typically listed to reduce possibility of excess /heat/ buildup in the fixture.  If you want to use 3x 60 watt bulbs, consider replacing traditional incandescent bulbs with newer CFL (spiral) or LED bulbs.  Either choice will use much less electricity and also emit much less heat, staying within the safety rating for the fixture.